# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database

I had an requirement to Create Database through windows service, when first time service will run,when i am running Create Db Script from WPF application it successfully create database but same script when i am running from Windows service i am getting error "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Comment: Does the account your service is using, have permission to access the master database ? services - <your service> - properties - LogOn Tab

Answer (score 1):

The Windows service account needs to be a member of the SQL Server sysadmin role or the db_creator server role in order to create databases.  Adding the below script to your script may help you.

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS;
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE', 'sysadmin';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into an administrator issue.

Before opening the program, right click on it and run it as administrator.

Hopefully this should solve your problem.